# lsusb partially fails, is the problem with the USB bus or with the command?

Tags: linux, usb

What does

> Couldn't get configuration descriptor 0, some information will be missing

mean? **Did the Host fail to get the descriptor from the device, or the command `lsusb` failed to fetch that information?** Surely the device couldn't have enumerated successfully if the mandatory Configuration Descriptor was unsuccessfully missing!

Context: This is a USB 3.0 device, that I am currently programming. It should represent itself as two different speaker channels (playback and recording interfaces with each a single Isochronous asynchronious endpoint). The device enumerates successfully under Windows 7 64 bit.

System: Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

```
sw3@pc90313-sw3:/dev/bus/usb/004$ sudo lsusb -D 009
[sudo] password for sw3: 
Device: ID aaaa:bbbb  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0xaaaa 
  idProduct          0xbbbb 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           1 Cypress
  iProduct                2 FX3
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
Couldn't get configuration descriptor 0, some information will be missing
Couldn't get configuration descriptor 0, some information will be missing
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```